# using CollectionAdminRequest.Create from SolrJ to create a collection

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

How can I use CollectionAdminRequest.Create in SolrJ to create a new collection in SolrCloud running with zookeeper.

I tried

```
    public void createIndex(String targetUuid) {
            HttpSolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/").build();


            try {
                // 1. Create Index with two shards and one replicas
                if(uploadConfigset()) {
                    //Error Here    
                    CollectionAdminRequest.Create creator = new CollectionAdminRequest.Create(targetUuid,"tg_configset",1,2,0,0);
                    creator.setMaxShardsPerNode(2);
                    creator.process(solrClient);
                }
            } catch (IOException | SolrServerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

But can not use CollectionAdminRequest.Create as its constructor is 'protected'

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the [CollectionAdminRequest.createCollection](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_4_2/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/CollectionAdminRequest.html#createCollection-java.lang.String-int-int-) methods. You're not supposed to call the constructor directly any longer, as it has been deprecated for the `createCollection` methods on the CollectionAdminRequest class.

```
CollectionAdminRequest.Create creator = CollectionAdminRequest.createCollection("newcollection", "tg_configset", 1, 2)
```

This still returns a `CollectionAdminRequest.Create` object, so the rest of the code should work as you'd expect.

Comment: At the moment I made it work like 
`Create creator = new CollectionAdminRequest.Create(Index_Uuid, "my_configset", 1,
     2, 0, 0) {

    /**
     * TODO: javadoc
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1253482406944674434L;
   };
   creator.setMaxShardsPerNode(2);
   creator.process(solr);`

Comment: I will try it wil `CollectionAdminRequest.createCollection`